# Detect TWAIN Duplex

Tags: twain, twaindotnet

Using TWAIN to capture images from a scanner, I'm trying to determine if the open scanner has duplex scanning enabled.  I know that if I use the DG_CONTROL/DAT_CAPABILITY/MSG_GETCURRENT triplet to fetch the CAP_DUPLEX capability, then it will tell me whether or not the scanner supports duplex scanning, but I need to know whether or not duplex is currently enabled.  Is there a capability that I can get that will tell me whether or not duplex is enabled, not just supported?

Comment: Which scanner? I have some bad news for you, they are rarely truly TWAIN compliant, and most scanners have custom tags.

Answer (score 0):

Ther is another TWAIN capability - CAP_DUPLEXENABLED which serves for that.